# Git commands not working without sudo in vagrant machine

Tags: git, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I have a project on my vagrant machine that I would like to push into my github repository. But I cannot add objects without using `sudo`.

1. I have initialized git

   ```
   vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/testDir$ git init
   Initialized empty Git repository in /vagrant/testDir/.git/`
   ```
2. After that if I run the command to add contents

   ```
   vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/testDir$ git add .`
   ```

   Then I am getting this error:

> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
>
> error: file1: failed to insert into database
>
> error: unable to index file file1
>
> fatal: adding files failed

Although I can run the command without any errors if I run with `sudo`, i.e., `sudo git add .`.

I have confirmed the permission inside the project, and they are are okay:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/testDir$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 160 Dec 23 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 160 Dec 23 10:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 352 Dec 23 10:33 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   0 Dec 23 10:33 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   0 Dec 23 10:33 file2.txt
```

I have ubuntu 18.04 on my vagrant machine running on macOS High Sierra.
Vagrant = 2.2.2
Virtual box = 6.0.8 r130520

Could you please help me out?

**Update 1**

Also, the permission on `.git/` directory are fine

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/testDir/.git$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 320 Dec 23 10:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 160 Dec 23 04:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  23 Dec 23 04:12 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  64 Dec 23 04:12 branches
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 111 Dec 23 04:12 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  73 Dec 23 04:12 description
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 416 Dec 23 04:12 hooks
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  96 Dec 23 04:12 info
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 160 Dec 23 04:12 objects
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 128 Dec 23 04:12 refs
```

**Update 2**

The permission inside the `.git/objects` directory are also okay.

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/testDir/.git/objects$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 160 Dec 23 11:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 320 Dec 23 11:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  96 Dec 23 11:06 e6
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  64 Dec 23 11:06 info
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  64 Dec 23 11:06 pack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps I took to solve my problem:

1. I downgraded the virtualbox on my macOS from 6.0.8 r130520 to 6.0.4 r128413.
2. Installed [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) plugin

   `$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`
3. Reload the vagrant machine.

   `user@MacBook-Pro vagrant-project-machine $ vagrant reload
   ==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
   ==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04' is up to date...
   ...
   ...
   ==> default: Machine booted and ready!
   ...
   [default] GuestAdditions versions on your host (6.0.4) and guest (6.0.8) do not match.
   ...
   ...
   The following additional packages will be installed:
     linux-headers-4.15.0-51
   ...
   ...`

Finally you can confirm it by running this command:

```
user@MacBook-Pro vagrant-project-machine $ vagrant vbguest --status
...
...
[default] GuestAdditions 6.0.4 running --- OK.
```

You can also confirm inside the vagrant machine by running this command:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/testDir$ modinfo vboxguest
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-51-generic/misc/vboxguest.ko
version:        6.0.4 r128413
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     95F53B9B95BC6E03156A1D8
alias:          pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc*sc*i*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           vboxguest
vermagic:       4.15.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload
```

Now I can run the git commands without using `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

> if the check the permission of the contents, the permissions are okay:

They are, on the first level.
But are they in `.git/objects`?

You might want to do, to be sure, a `sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant .git`

Add also the [`core.sharedRepository`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresharedRepository) setting:

```
git config --global core.sharedRepository group
```

The [OP Kakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018197/kakar) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453889/git-commands-not-working-without-sudo-in-vagrant-machine/59454016?noredirect=1#comment105095059_59454016) the [`hashicorp/vagrant` issue 10913](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10913), which states:

> I believe the bug is in the Guest Additions so you need to make sure the correct version of those are installed.
>   Run `modinfo vboxguest` in Ubuntu to find out the version that is installed.
>
> I appear to have solved this by updating my Virtualbox Guest Additions from 6.0.10 to 6.0.12, using [`dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest`](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest).

Comment: I ran the command you recommended but the errors are still there if I run the command without `sudo`. Also the permission on .git/objects are fine, I have updated the post.

Comment: What about one level more, inside `.git/objects`?

Comment: @Kakar Can you try again after `git config --global core.sharedRepository group`?

Comment: @tripleee The permissions are fine on that level too. I have updated the post.

Comment: @VonC It is still same.

Comment: @Kakar Even after recreating the git repository?

Comment: @VonC Yes, even then. I came across this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10913) in github. May there's a bug.

Comment: @Kakar Good point. i have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Okay. I was solved the issue by downgrading the virtualbox and answered the steps for it. Thank you!